# Recommendations for OM blogs

Tags: optimization, inventory, supply-chain

Could someone suggest good blogs to follow for researchers in Operations Management/ Supply Chain Management /Operations Research?

Comment: https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2020/

Comment: Here's a nice blog for OM educators that is updated very regularly: https://heizerrenderom.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 15):

Here is the list of blogs and social media that I regularly check [in no particular order]:

- https://www.zverovich.net/
- https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/
- https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/
- http://erlingdandersen.blogspot.com/
- https://punkrockor.com/
- https://lemire.me/blog/
- https://nathanbrixius.wordpress.com/
- https://themosekblog.blogspot.com/
- https://annanagurney.blogspot.com/
- http://www.optimisationintherealworld.co.uk/blog/
- http://fa.bianp.net/
- https://thiagoserra.com/blog/
- https://blogs.princeton.edu/imabandit/
- https://towardsdatascience.com/
- https://medium.com/opex-analytics
- http://stegua.github.io/
- http://matthewcrews.com/
- https://optano.com/en/blog/
- https://francisbach.com/
- https://mluebbecke.wordpress.com/ [in German]
- https://www.gurobi.com/resources/?category-filter=blog

Answer (score 7):

For OM, you might like [Jay, Barry and Chuck's OM Blog](https://heizerrenderom.wordpress.com/).
For OR, I like [OR in Devon, UK](https://orindevon.blogspot.com/) as well as many of the entries in Richard's excellent answer. I had a few other OR blogs that I liked, but sadly their owners appear to have stopped posting.

Answer (score 6):

Our blog might be useful too:

- https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/

We cover OR use cases (just did an article on [Covid Appointment Scheduling](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2021/03/04/OptimizingCovid19VaccinationScheduling.html)), our technology and general insights.

Comment: I think the use of the first person ("our blog", "we cover", "our technology") pretty much gives that away.

Answer (score 5):

SAS (my employer) has several blogs.  Here are two relevant tags:

- https://blogs.sas.com/content/tag/optimization/
- https://blogs.sas.com/content/tag/operations-research/