# Recommendations for OR video channels (YouTube etc.)

Tags: online-resources

The other day someone asked about [recommended blogs to follow](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5885/recommendations-for-om-blogs).

The older generation tends to prefer blog posts, but the newer generations tend to watch videos instead.
And we want to help the newer generations find their way to Operations Research, no?

So which YouTube channels and other video channels would you recommend for following OR?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some of the playlists I enjoyed:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2QgdDk4Xjw&list=PL05350A31E6C09B7A *fundamentals of operations research*
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4U3B5lr-MqM&list=PL004010FEA702502F *advanced topics in operations research*
- https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOEpD2bjMC9JsTBCafj8Fs5ChDdRqjw5j *Operations & Supply chain mangagement*

Answer (score 9):

Here are some YouTube channels having research level talks, all of which were livestreamed with live Q&A prior to being archived. These are all ongoing series with new talks (videos) added regularly.

[Discrete Optimization Talks](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbUviq3XZCrpjn5qlsTP5Zw)

[One World Optimization Seminar](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMXtHAfnKRntVKzPCUIiJnw)

[Communications in NLA](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSlAhBOIY68IWLxpPUFHuSQ) (Numerical Linear Algebra), which has many talks pertinent to optimization, as well as some in optimization per se.

Given the research level of these talks, they are more generally better suited for people who have already found their way to Operations Research, or at least a closely neighboring field, than for neophytes.

[Euro Working Group on OR Practice](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=kbTctalK)

**Edit**: Additional seminar series:

[Machine Learning NeEDS (Network of European Data Scientists) Mathematical Optimization](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCB_MDxNsfAX9nGIy82EGS0A) This series includes a number of presentations from leading academics in the field of Data Science and Analytics that will cover important topics such as explainability, fairness, fraud, privacy, etc. Mathematical Modeling and Mathematical Optimization will be at the core of their presentations. We also have the YOUNG Online Seminar Series “Machine Learning NeEDS Mathematical Optimization”.

**Edit2** There is a new [Robust Optimization YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/@robustoptimizationwebinar/about). It has a collection of Robust Optimization webinar talks, which can be attended live by signing up at the [Robust Optimization Webinar (ROW) web page](https://sites.google.com/view/row-series/home?pli=1).

Answer (score 6):

The [Gurobi YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/GurobiVideos/videos) has great collection of videos covering industry webinars, technical tutorials and primers on LP & MIP.

The [Mixed Integer Programming channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCphLz_BXrOAInHozAlTsigA/videos) hosts all recorded lectures of the [CO@Work 2020](http://co-at-work.zib.de/) summer school as well as the invited talks from [EURO working group on Practice of OR 2020 meeting](https://www.euro-online.org/websites/or-in-practice/ewg-por-2020-challenges-in-the-deployment-of-or-projects/).

Answer (score 3):

There's the [Octeract YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwycy9aiePMk-rmj-5-i-mg?sub_confirmation=1) where we host a web series called [Optimisation for Noobz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RIR6Y5N63U&ab_channel=Octeract).

Answer (score 3):

This [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKMY2i-ROJjOXCxePFewnkg) posts interviews with researchers in OR.

Also, this [YouTube channel by Sebustien Bubeck](https://www.youtube.com/c/SebastienBubeck/playlists) covers optimization and ML topics.

Answer (score 3):

Here are few more YouTube channels related to OR

- [Optimus Prime](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2FECDvMphKdqi8RnFGD3Bg) -  Lecture series on Introduction of LP and MILP by Professor: Alberto Del Pia, University of Wisconsin-Madison
- [The OR Society](https://www.youtube.com/user/TheORSocietyUK)
- [GAMS Lessons](https://www.youtube.com/user/GAMSLessons)
- [AIMMS Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/AIMMSChannel)
- [AMPL Optimization](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6Yt3duW9a2IFj3nO2ZL6Ew/featured)
- [Supply Chain Academy](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZ1IbFCz_jiB7-RwOoTLCkg)
- [NeEDS - Network of European Data Scientists](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCB_MDxNsfAX9nGIy82EGS0A)
- [James Davis](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsZ5SOyr3XLIa3zXJsxkeXQ/featured) -  Videos on LP and MILP methods and algorithms
- [Yong Wang](https://www.youtube.com/c/YongWang/about) - This Youtube channel hosts some of the courses taught by Dr. Yong Wang
- [Decision Making 101](https://www.youtube.com/c/DecisionMaking101/featured)
- [Operations Management 101](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCP9j0k-u0Stlm3x-aV-NdVQ)

Answer (score 2):

Let me start by adding these as a community wiki (the first one is our channel):

- [OptaPlanner YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcpkOKpujFlM67D2h0RdaeQ)
- [INFORMS YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCCwr0VjkxPvbt9xNmKOHHFA)
- [SAS Statistics and Operations Research YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0B05D53A5E101AA6)

Answer (score 2):

On a different note (not a course), I recently found [Subject to](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKMY2i-ROJjOXCxePFewnkg/featured). It is more like an OR-oriented podcast.